# How can I center this vbox within the center region of this borderpane?

Tags: java, javafx, vbox, borderpane

I'm trying to create the first window of a game, and creating a menu to be placed in the center of this first screen.

```
    BorderPane bp = new BorderPane();
Button Start = new Button("Start");
Button Mute = new Button("Mute");
Button Exit = new Button("Quit");
Button Options = new Button("Options");

/*
 * Vbox in Center for buttons:
 * (non-Javadoc)
 * @see javafx.application.Application#start(javafx.stage.Stage)
 */

public void start(Stage primaryStage) {

    VBox vb = new VBox(100);
    vb.getChildren().addAll(Start,Options,Mute,Exit);
    vb.setMargin(Start, new Insets(0,0,0,15));
    vb.setMargin(Options, new Insets(0,0,0,15));
    vb.setMargin(Mute, new Insets(0,0,0,15));
    vb.setMargin(Exit, new Insets(0,0,0,15));
    bp.setCenter(vb);

    Scene scene = new Scene(bp, WIDTH, HEIGHT);
    primaryStage.setTitle("Tetris");
    primaryStage.setScene(scene);
    primaryStage.show();
}
```

Comment: I suggest you try it with SceneBuilder until you get it right. Then you can, if you so wish, implement it in code rather in FXML. I suppose you have a good reason not to use FXML.

Comment: thanks! Do you think part of the problem is the Insets?

Answer (score 0):

The key here is `vb.setMaxSize(Control.USE_PREF_SIZE, Control.USE_PREF_SIZE);`. I set a background color on the `VBox` so that you can see what's happening better.

```
    BorderPane bp = new BorderPane();
    Button Start = new Button("Start");
    Button Mute = new Button("Mute");
    Button Exit = new Button("Quit");
    Button Options = new Button("Options");

    VBox vb = new VBox(100);
    vb.setStyle("-fx-background-color: yellow");
    vb.getChildren().addAll(Start,Options,Mute,Exit);
    vb.setMargin(Start, new Insets(0,0,0,15));
    vb.setMargin(Options, new Insets(0,0,0,15));
    vb.setMargin(Mute, new Insets(0,0,0,15));
    vb.setMargin(Exit, new Insets(0,0,0,15));
    vb.setMaxSize(Control.USE_PREF_SIZE, Control.USE_PREF_SIZE);
    bp.setCenter(vb);

    Scene scene = new Scene(bp, 500, 720);
    primaryStage.setTitle("Tetris");
    primaryStage.setScene(scene);
    primaryStage.show();
```

[image]